# Words with dual and opposing meanings

Tags: word-property, english

What is the word in each case?

1. I can attach or cut.
2. I can be virtual or real.
3. I can approve or penalize.
4. I can separate or entangle.

Answer (score 3):

Four words that satisfy these double definitions are:

*1. I can attach or cut.*

> **[CLIP](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clip)** (and also **[CLEAVE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cleave)**, courtesy of @msh210 in comments)

*2. I can be virtual or real.*

> **[LITERAL(LY)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally)** ('virtually' when used in the colloquial sense...)

*3. I can approve or penalize.*

> **[SANCTION](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanction)** (and also **[ENDORSE](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/endorse)**, albeit more commonly in the UK in the context of driving licence penalty points re the 'penalize' definition)

*4. I can separate or entangle.*

> **[RAVEL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravel)**

In fact, there's a word to describe words like these:

> [**Auto-antonyms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) - words with multiple meanings which are the reverse of one another.

Comment: Absolutely correct! I was quite pleased when I discovered the existence of these words.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I toyed with rot13(RAQBEFR) for the third one also, since in the UK we use that word to describe both backing a candidate and adding penalty points to a driving licence, but I figured the one I went for was probably more internationally known...

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that word could also mean penalize. Interesting. Perhaps worth adding a note to the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: #1 can also be rot13(gb pyrnir).

Comment: @msh210 That's true - I'll add that as an additional option, thanks.

Comment: I don't think ENDORSE really does it for #2. What's being endorsed in the "penalize" sense is neither the offence nor the offender, but a document associated with them, namely their driving licence. To my mind, that isn't quite opposite to the "approve of" meaning, where it's applied to an action one approves of or a candidate one's backing.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan There's a reason it only appears in brackets rather than as part of my main answer (and indeed was only added during a later edit) - I knew that one would be less obvious. However, I would still say that receiving points on a driving licence is a penalty, so the person putting the points on - i.e. endorsing the licence - is applying a penalty, or 'penalizing'. Like I say, 'sanction' is definitely stronger, but I do think there's a case for this one too, even though a little weaker :)